# What are test cases in Python Programming

Tags: python-3.x

Im not sure I fully understand what they mean by including text cases in my code.
I am suppose to do a 4 step design such as (Declarations, Input/Output/pseudo code/test cases)

What exactly is a test case and what would be an example using my code below.

```
# ********************************************************
#
# Winnings is the amount Max Won which is 1000000
# Years is a placeholder to define the variable
# Loop winnings - 52000 and cound the amount of years,
# until 52000 can not be withdrew from account
# print the number of years.
#
# ********************************************************

def main():
    winnings = 1000000
    years = 0
    while winnings >= 52000:
        years = years + 1
        winnings = winnings - 52000
    print("Number of years Max can withdraw 52000 is",years)

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A test case is something that attempts to prove something about the operation of your code. If you break down the requirements of what your code needs to do you can translate these into separate test cases.

Maybe your test needs to assert that the number of years returned from the code is not negative? Perhaps it needs to assert that the winnings value is less than 52000 on termination of the code - this will be for you to decide based on what you think the code **should** be doing.

The test *case* in particular refers to the exact inputs/expected outputs you would apply to a single requirement. If you require winnings to be less than 52000 on termination, you would have the test case of no input, the condition of having run the code to completion and then the check of whether the winnings variable was less than 52000.